# Android My First App Tutorial android:onClick issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I am currently trying to get the basic My First App tutorial of Android (created by google) to work, but I'm having some issues. Currently how the app is made  no errors show up in Eclipse, but when I run the app and click the Send button, the app crashes displaying `Unfortunately, My First App has stopped.`

Looking in the Log cat for the error it states that

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) 
in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity for onClick handler 
on view class android.widget.Button.
```

`sendMessage` does exist in the `MainActivity` class, but it is a nested class inside a function `PlaceholderFragment`. Originally I thought that this was an indexing error so I tried calling `sendMessage` like a nested class `android:onClick="PlaceholderFragment.sendMessage"` with no success. I have included the `fragment_main` and `MainActivity` class as well as my full logcat error. Thanks for any help.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
    * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        public void sendMessage(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

Fragment Main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
04-25 12:04:07.220: D/(1274): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8e4f238, tid 1274
04-25 12:04:07.330: W/EGL_emulation(1274): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-25 12:04:07.340: D/OpenGLRenderer(1274): Enabling debug mode 0
04-25 12:04:10.620: D/AndroidRuntime(1274): Shutting down VM
04-25 12:04:10.620: W/dalvikvm(1274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a6bba8)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1274
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sendMessage [class android.view.View]
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
04-25 12:04:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     ... 11 more
04-25 12:04:12.720: I/Process(1274): Sending signal. PID: 1274 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that the sendMessage function should be included in your MainActivity instead of nested in your fragment.

The debug line:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
```

shows that the application is looking in your MainActivity class for this method.

Comment: When I do that this error appears "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity" I'm guessing getActivity() is a function included in Androids support libraries for the PlaceholderFragment class.

Answer (score 0):

place `sendMessage(View view)` method inside `MainActivity` class instead of `PlaceholderFragment` class

Answer (score 0):

Handling clicklistener from `xml` is not always a good idea. Set a clicklistener in the fragment for the button and call `sendMessage` method from `onClick` method of clicklistener.

First set a `ID` for your button (Example : sendButton).

Then,

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewByID(R.id.sendButton);
        //Here set the clickListener and call sendMessage method
        return rootView;
    }


    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Or implement `View.OnClickListener` in the fragment then have a case statement like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.sendButton:
            sendMessage();
            break;
        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "Unknown: " + view.getId());
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it programmatically:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // handle click here
            }
        });
        return rootView;
}
```

and insert this into Button section in your main activity layout:
    android:id="@+id/my_button"

Answer (score 0):

android:onClick="sendMessage"

button onClick attribute search the corresponding method in the Activity. but you define that method in the Fragment that's why you get the exception
method could not find exception.

Android Recommended way to do handle the onClick for button inside the fragment is
First Assign id to Button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
     />
   </LinearLayout>
```

your Fragment then register the button with onClick listener

```
/**
* A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment  implements OnItemClickListener{

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
     Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       sendMessage(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but I'm getting an error that is preventing me from importing OnClickListener 
    import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS.OnItemClickListener;//Error: The type android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS is not visible